# Increment Total in Loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, sum

I have loop like this :

```
Value A Value B Value C Total
   X       -       X    Total X
   X       -       X    Total X
   X       -       X    Total X
   X       -       X    Total X
   X       -       X    Total X
```

I want sum total X, this my code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Value A</th>
    <th>Value B</th>
    <th>Value C</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
    <?php
    for($ii = 1; $ii <= 3; $ii++) {
        $a = ($ii % 2 == 0) ? "-" : "X";
        echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
    }
    ?>
    <td>Total X</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Any tricks to make it sum with PHP?

Many Thanks!

Comment: if 'x' is number then you can just add them like `$total = $a + $b + $c;`  if $a, $b, $c are string number then you can convert them `(int)$a + (int)$b + (int)$c;` but don't forgot to check if it is number or it is just `-`

Comment: Where do these values come from , are they from an array?  Currently this doesn't show any values other than the row number so how are we supposed to know what to add up.

Comment: sorry, i have done update my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated from new code:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Value A</th>
    <th>Value B</th>
    <th>Value C</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { ?>
    <?php $total = 0; ?>
    <tr> 
        <?php 
            for($ii = 1; $ii <= 3; $ii++) { 
                $a = ($ii % 2 == 0) ? "-" : "X";
                if($a == "X") $total++;
                echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
            } 
        ?>
        <td><?php echo $total ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: i don't think that @Kemal wants to count. He wants just sum of them.

Comment: I think that's exactly what he want. Total X :)

Comment: sorry guys my code like this : <table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Value A</th>
    <th>Value B</th>
    <th>Value C</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
 <?php
 for($ii = 1; $ii <= 3; $ii++) {
  $a = ($ii % 2 == 0) ? "-" : "X";
  echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
 }
 ?>
    <td>Total X</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>

Comment: I have updated it. Let me know if it what you wanted. And if yes, please mark my answer as right one.

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as correct one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you should do is just convert it to `int` and then sum them:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Value A</th>
        <th>Value B</th>
        <th>Value C</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $a = ($i % 2 == 0) ? "10" : "-";
        $b = ($i % 2 == 0) ? "-" : "20";
        $c = ($i % 2 == 0) ? "15" : "-";
        $total = (int)$a + (int)$b + (int)$c;
        $res = "<tr>";
        $res .= "  <td>".$a."</td>";
        $res .= "  <td>".$b."</td>";
        $res .= "  <td>".$c."</td>";
        $res .= "  <td>Total ".$total."</td>";
        $res .= "</tr>";
        echo $res;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my code like this :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Value A</th>
    <th>Value B</th>
    <th>Value C</th>
    <th>Total</th>
</tr>
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
    <?php
    for($ii = 1; $ii <= 3; $ii++) {
        $a = ($ii % 2 == 0) ? "-" : "X";
        echo "<td>".$a."</td>";
    }
    ?>
    <td>Total X</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

And i want count the total of X
Any tricks to make it count with PHP

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting updates as an answer. To do this use the `edit` button below your question. And while you're at it, please elaborate how the *totaling* should work. How is the script supposed to sum up "X" and "-".

Comment: Thank you! Please also add an explanation of "Total X".

Comment: total X is from value A n Value B n Value C is dynamic loop

Comment: To your question :) Not here.